# Equal 3D icon size visualization in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, unity-webgl

I have some Icons (Sprite rendered in 3d world) whose icons are equal size (scale 1). Now I am trying to implement a solution that icons visually show at same size.  If you see the icon at distance then it looks very small when you near the icon then it look bigger. So I want to visualize them equally.

For this reason, first I got the near scale value which is .5 (suitable) and far scale maybe around 1.5. Now, here is my code but it producing very large scale value.

```
 void Update()
    {
        foreach (var item in iconsObjects)
        {
            
            float size = Vector3.Distance(activeCamera.position, item.transform.position);
            if (size < 2000)//for optimization purpsose only conside near object under 2000m distance
            {
                float finalSize = Mathf.Clamp(size, 0.5f, 2f);
                item.localScale = new Vector3(finalSize, finalSize, finalSize);
            }
            

        }
    }
```

I thought Mahtf.Clamp will work within the context but it is not suitable here as it is applying scale 2 to the near objects where it should be around .5.

Comment: So just to clarify, with this code the resulting `finalSize` on some icons is larger than 2? Why are you discarding icons further than 2000 units, but restricting the scaling to only happen within an interval of 1.5 units? What exactly is your question? How to achieve the equal size regardless of distance? Or how to fix the code you have to do something like that?

Comment: yes even 400. I am discarding icons so that the scale should not apply to far objects.

Comment: In what way is Mathf.Clamp not suitable here? Can you show us the look you're getting with this code?

Comment: Scale 2 is applying for near object as well.

Answer (score 1):

This code tries to scale objects to the visible size they'd have if they were 1 unit away from the camera.

That's awfully close to use as a benchmark size! A sprite that's 1m from your camera would be quite large, so a sprite that's just 1 unit farther away would need to *double* in size to match it.

That means you saturate your upper scaling limit almost immediately, leaving no headroom for the more distant objects.

Instead, you can pick a farther distance to use as your scaling reference point. Something like...

```
// First, only count distance along the camera's axis.
// (This is more uniform across your screen, and cheaper!)
Vector3 fromCamera = item.transform.position - activeCamera.position;

float distance = Vector3.Dot(fromCamera, activeCamera.forward);

// Vary this to set the distance where sprites should have scale 1.
float referenceDistance = 100f;

// Vary this to set the closest objects that should be scaled to match.
// Anything closer will appear larger.
float minDistance = 1.0f;

// Vary this to set the farthest objects that should be scaled to match.
// Anything farther will appear smaller.
float maxDistance = 200f;

float effectiveDistance = Mathf.Clamp(distance, minDistance, maxDistance);

float relativeScale  = effectiveDistance / referenceDistance;

item.transform.localScale = new Vector3(relativeScale, relativeScale, relativeScale);
```

Comment: I am sorry but don't you think that the object near the camera should be smaller and the far object should be bigger. So that we can visualize the icons equally?

Comment: That is what this code does, yes. The minDistance and maxDistance variables are, as the variable names say, distances, not sizes.

Comment: You might be getting mixed up with the comments describing what happens to icons closer than the minimum distance, or farther than the maximum distance. Just like your current code, this code equalizes the visible size of icons within a certain range: it never scales icons down more than a certain amount, or scales them up more than a certain amount. I just chose to phrase those limits as distances to make it clearer what choice you're making when you set them. In your current code, reference distance is 1, min distance is 0.5, and max distance is 2. You can set the limits to 0/∞ if you prefer

Comment: I see that its applying the same scaling to a far object